# "Type Error: lambda is not a function" in handler with multiple functions

Tags: javascript, serverless-framework

I have two functions in my handler.js file and I have configured them correctly in serverless.yml. The problem is, when I run invocation, only the first one work and the second one throws a type error: "lambda is not a function".

I made sure there are no spelling mistakes in my yml file or in the handler file. Also, I tried putting the functions into separate files. None of them work.

In my handler.js I have

```
const one = async (event, context, callback) => {
//code here
};

const two = async (event, context, callback) => {
//code here
};

module.exports = {
one,
two
};
```

In my yml file I have

```
functions:
  one:
    handler: handler.one
    events:
      - http: POST one
  two:
    handler: handler.two,
    events:
      - http: POST two
```

Calling `one` works fine but calling `two` throws an error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the frame work, but I see that handler.two has a comma while handler.one does not.  Try removing the comma.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! It works now! Thanks. Must have been too tired and overlooked it by accident